# Directory Math Error with [i]

Tags: python

I was working on a simple math solver, and I created a directory where the user's inputs would store:

```
data = {
       'name': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: ''},      
       'quantity': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'soldin': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'price': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'yld': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'apc': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'epc': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 
       'exc': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
       }
```

I also had the code which would solve the problem in question (the i is set within the program based on how many data sets the user inputted):

```
i = 2
while(i >=0):
   first = data['soldin'][i]
   second = data['price'][i]
   apco = float(data[first][i])/float(doug)
   epco = apco/data['yld'][i]
   i = i - i
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 31, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Your dictionaries don't have entries for the key `0`, they all start at `1`. So maybe you should only loop `while i > 0`.

Comment: Agreed. Voting to close as typo

Comment: The error message is fairly specific. Did you research what `KeyError` means?

Answer (score 2):

Your `dict` has no entries with the `key` `0`.
That's why you get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 31, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

One solution could be, to change the `while` condition.

```
while(i >=0):
```

to:

```
while(i > 0):
```

Hope this helps.